# Cuban going to London. Transit visa at Madrid required?

Tags: transit-visas

I am a Cuban. I am traveling to London and acquired plane tickets from Air Europa, which goes through Madrid. Do I need a transit visa to switch planes at Madrid?

Comment: No. As long as you do not have to leave transit zone, you are fine.

Comment: @OleksandrKravchuk Is there a source for this?

Comment: @becko The answer you commented provides links to all the relevant sources. The provision exempting UK visa holders from the airport transit visa requirement is to be found in article 3(5)(c) of regulation 810/2009 (i.e. the Schengen Visa Code).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The source is Timatic, the database used by the airlines for passport and visa requirements, nationals of Cuba with an onward ticket to the UK may transit Spain without a visa.

[image]

Comment: Can you give me a link to access this database? Thanks.

Comment: @becko there are many, but the one I used, [Emirates](https://www.emirates.com/english/before-you-fly/visa-passport-information/find-visa-requirements.aspx), is easiest IMO